# Yes/No dialog and the lifecycle

Tags: android, dialog, onclick, lifecycle

I'm sure this is a fundamental question, but my research yields nothing useful.  My new application needs to use a Yes/No dialog under a few circumstances, and I'm not getting how dialogs fit into the application lifecycle.  For example, I would like to create a method to support this type of construct:

```
if (yesNoAlert("Title", "Do you want to try again?") == true) {
   action1();
} else {
   action2();
}
```

The method would look something like this:

```
private boolean yesNoAlert(String title, String message) {
    final boolean returnValue;

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new
                       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                returnValue = true;
                break;

            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                returnValue=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setMessage(message)
            .setTitle(title)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
            .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener)
            .show();
}
```

... but as you can see, it is not finished - there are a number of things not quiet correct about it.  The piece I'm missing is how to know that the dialog has finished... what method exists that can be utilized so that the application can pick up on the fact that the button has been pressed?  Of course, the BUTTON_POSITIVE and BUTTON_NEGATIVE actions respond to that, but my question is how to *return* with an indicator, so that the code that's waiting for a response will pick up again at action1() or action2(), depending upon response.

At present, I do not see any way for my application to determine this, - nor even a valid way to make a method/function from that code.  so I'm missing some vital piece from the lifecycle.

Where might I read up on this?  Of course, there are volumes of information available on internet about this, but for me as a relative newbie it's like trying drink from a fire hose.

Comment: Make the returnValue variable a "class variable" instead of a "local method variable".  Then you would be able to set 'returnValue' from within the onClick method.

Answer (score 2):

This will make the action that needs to be taken dynamic:

```
private Thread actionToDo;

private void yesNoAlert(String title, String message)
{
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                switch (which)
                {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                    actionToDo.start();
                    break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                    break;
                }
            }
    };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).setTitle(title).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this

```
private boolean yesNoAlert(String title, String message) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
        .setTitle(title)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { action1(); }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { action2(); }
        })
        .show();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  But there are several places within the code where a Yes/No question may apply... and the result would be that all the program logic might get buried under Yes/No dialogs.  Consider what might happen, for example with:

while userIsEnergetic {
    doSomething(result);
    if (result == AN_ERROR) {
        if (yesNoAlert(TITLE, "An error occurred.  Keep trying?")) {
        } else {
        if (yesNoAlert(TITLE, "Try something else?")) {
            youGetTheDrill();
        }
    }

Comment: @Dennis the problem is that you cannot return true/false value from `yesNoAlert`. Calling `show()` on a dialog does NOT block until user clicks on yes or no button. Instead, the appropriate `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` will be called later on main ui thread. If you want to separate the logic from AlertDialog, then you could for example make the yes/no `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` as instance variables.

Comment: @Dennis such procedural approach will not work. you have to switch your code which interacts with user into event-based model.

Comment: thanks for the tips.  My main problem is that I learned programming - and have been quite successful - many years ago, under a completely different paradigm.  I can do this, but some of the retraining is essential.  I appreciate your direction, and will continue the search for information about the differences between paradigms.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a listener to achieve this. Like said in android documentation:

1. Define a interface with the actions you need to support (`onDialogPositiveClick` and `onDialogNegativeClick`).

   public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

   ```
   /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
    * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
    * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
   public interface NoticeDialogListener {
       public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog);
       public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
   }

   // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
   NoticeDialogListener mListener;

   // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
   @Override
   public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
       // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
       try {
           // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
           mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
           throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
       }
   }
   ...
   ```

   }
2. Make the class that displays the dialog implements your interface.

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                             implements NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener{
       ...

   ```
   public void showNoticeDialog() {
       // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
       DialogFragment dialog = new NoticeDialogFragment();
       dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");
   }

   // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
   // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
   // defined by the NoticeDialogFragment.NoticeDialogListener interface
   @Override
   public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
       // User touched the dialog's positive button
       ...
   }

   @Override
   public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {
       // User touched the dialog's negative button
       ...
   }
   ```

   }
3. Make your dialog invoke these methods on the correct moment (when detect `setPositiveButton` or `setNegativeButton` click).

   public class NoticeDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
       ...

   ```
   @Override
   public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
       builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
              .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      // Send the positive button event back to the host activity
                      mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                  }
              })
              .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                      // Send the negative button event back to the host activity
                      mListener.onDialogNegativeClick(NoticeDialogFragment.this);
                  }
              });
       return builder.create();
   }
   ```

   }

Ref http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents